# Error Loading DataFrame to BigQuery Table (pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: object of type <class 'str'> cannot be converted to int)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, google-bigquery, pyarrow

I have a CSV stored in GCS which I want to load it to BigQuery table. But I need to do some pre-process first so I load it to DataFrame and later load to BigQuery table

```
import pandas as pd
import json 
from google.cloud import bigquery


cols_name_list = [....]. # column name in order
uri = "gs://<bucket>/<path>/<csv_file>"
df = pd.read_csv(uri, dtype="string")
df =df.reindex(columns=cols_name_list)

client = bigquery.Client()
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
   ... # added all schema field according to table column type
)

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    df, "<bq_table_id>", job_config=job_config
)
job.result()
```

From code above, I reorder the dataframe column order to match with the order in BigQuery table (not sure if this matter or not) and convert all column to be string type.

I got this error as shown below in which

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Could not convert '47803' with type str: tried to convert to int
```

I also ran it without forcing the dtypes to be string and I got another error

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: Expected a string or bytes dtype, got int64
```

The code and data looks normal. So, I tried downgrading the version of numpy and pyarrow and still cause the same error.

**Update:**

I updated the code to force only string column

```
df =pd.read_csv(uri, dtype={"B" : "string"})
```

This is the example CSV data that I worked with

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
47803,000000000020030263,629,,2021-01-12 23:26:37,,
```

where column type of BQ table should be like this

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField("A", "INTEGER"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("B", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("C", "INTEGER"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("D", "INTEGER"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("E", "DATETIME"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("F", "INTEGER"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("G", "DATETIME")
    ]
)
```

Now, when I'm trying to load data with `load_table_from_dataframe()` with these configs, I got this error

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: object of type <class 'str'> cannot be converted to int
```

So, I print the dtypes out

```
A      int64
B      string
C      int64
D      float64
E      object
F      float64
G      float64
dtype: object
```

Which column that is the issue right now and how can I fix this? The error is not quite useful for debugging. Since the column that supposed to be int is already int. The only column with string type no need to be converted to int but the error thrown like that

Comment: Hi @Jamiewp, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve the answer.

Answer (score 15):

You have to set the `source_format` to the format of the source data inside your LoadJobConfig. In this case you can set `autodetect=False` as you have explicitly specified the schema of the table. Below is the sample according to which you can make changes in your code and try to execute.

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
 
    schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField("A", "INTEGER"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("B", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("C", "INTEGER"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("D", "INTEGER"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("E", "DATETIME"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("F", "INTEGER"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("G", "DATETIME")
    ],
    autodetect=False,
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
)
```

**CSV Data:**

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
47803,000000000020030263,629,785,2021-01-12 23:26:37,986,2022-01-12 23:26:37
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I tried adding both `autodetect` and `source_format` and it working. But seems like if I just add only the `autodetect` without adding the `source_format`. The error still shown. Any idea why this happen?

Comment: @Jamiewp, I have edited my answer as per your query.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue, but I'm trying to use pandas.to_bgq

This is my code:

```
#transform new_data to pandas dataframe. new_data is a JSON 

    new_data = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=['FechaHora', 'Fecha', 'Hora', 'Entrada', 'Grupo1', 'HourlyCountOne', 'HourlyCountTwo', 'Variacion', 'sumToAforo', 'DiaSemana', 'Tipo', 'NDiaSemana'])
    print("new_data.dtypes: ", new_data.dtypes)

    if new_data['FechaHora'].dtype == 'object':
        new_data['FechaHora'] = pd.to_datetime(new_data['FechaHora'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

    new_data['HourlyCountOne'] = pd.to_numeric(new_data['HourlyCountOne'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
    new_data['HourlyCountTwo'] = pd.to_numeric(new_data['HourlyCountTwo'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
    new_data['Variacion'] = pd.to_numeric(new_data['Variacion'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
    new_data['NDiaSemana'] = pd.to_numeric(new_data['NDiaSemana'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
    
    print("new_data.dtypes: ", new_data.dtypes)

    #print new_data row by row
    for index, row in new_data.iterrows():
        #print the row as a single string
        print(f"{index}={row.to_string()}")
    
    pandas_gbq.to_gbq(new_data, 'project_id.dataset.table_id', project_id='project_id', if_exists='append')
    
    print("Loaded {} rows into {}.".format(len(new_data), 'project-id.dataset.tableid'))
    return "Loaded {} rows into {}.".format(len(new_data), 'project-id.dataset.tableid')
```

when I deploy and run the function, I'm getting the error:

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: object of type <class 'str'> cannot be converted to int
```

I'm unable to find what column or value is causing the issue.

This is the bigquery table schema:

```
FechaHora:DATETIME,
Fecha:DATE,
Hora:TIME,
Entrada:STRING,
Grupo1:STRING,
HourlyCountOne:INTEGER,
HourlyCountTwo:INTEGER,
Variacion:INTEGER,
sumToAforo:BOOLEAN,
DiaSemana:STRING,
Tipo:STRING,
NDiaSemana:INTEGER
```

This is the printed dtypes of new_data

```
FechaHora datetime64[ns]
Fecha object 
Hora object 
Entrada object 
Grupo1 object 
HourlyCountOne int64 
HourlyCountTwo int64 
Variacion int64 
sumToAforo bool 
DiaSemana object 
Tipo object 
NDiaSemana int64
```

This is the output when I print the first row of the pandas dataframe:

```
0=FechaHora 2023-09-27 04:00:00
Fecha 2023-09-27
Hora 04:00:00
Entrada Entrada Motos
Grupo1 Entrada Motos
HourlyCountOne 9
HourlyCountTwo 0
Variacion 9
sumToAforo False
DiaSemana Miércoles
Tipo Moto
NDiaSemana 4
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a solution for your issue, specifically, but I've face the same problem and realized that the .to_gbd() retrieves the original table schema. Deleting the previously created table solves this issue to any dtype, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with load_table_from_dataframe. I guess there is some issue which needs to be checked since it only works when all 3 are passed (schema, autodetect set to False, source_format set to bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV). I didn't want to replicate the schema again since I want to maintain it only at one place in my terraform.

I changed my code like below to read the existing BigQuery schema and pass it back during the write.

```
# Drop index from the pandas df
write_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# Get the dataset and table ref
dataset_ref = client.dataset("DATASET")
table_ref = dataset_ref.table("TABLE")

# Set the job config
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
job_config.schema = client.get_table(table_ref).schema
job_config.autodetect = False
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV

# Write to BQ
load_job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
        write_df, table_ref,
        job_config=job_config)
```